# Python not able to find string in file

Tags: python-2.7

so I am writing a program to find specific lines in a dump from the uninstall registry, and then write those lines to a new text file. Here is the code.

```
fileName = "export.txt"
outputFileName = input("Enter the Output File Name")
inputFile = open(fileName, "r")
outputFile = open(outputFileName, "w")
displayName = ""
displayVersion = ""
publisher = ""

for line in inputFile:
    if "DisplayName" in line:
        lst = line.split("=")
        displayName = lst[1][1:len(lst[1])-1]

    if "DisplayVersion" in line:
        lst = line.split("=")
        displayVersion = lst[1][1:len(lst[1])-1]
    if "Publisher" in line:
        lst = line.split("=")
        publisher = lst[1][1:len(lst[1])-1]
    if displayName!= "" or displayVersion != "" or publisher != "":
        outputFile.write(displayName + "\t" + displayVersion + "\t" +publisher + "\n")
        displayName = ""
        displayVersion = ""
        publisher = ""

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

For some reason, the first three if statements are not being entered.  Here is a snippet from the export.txt text file.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SoftWare\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Matlab R2016b]
"DisplayName"="MATLAB R2016b"
"UninstallString"="C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\uninstall\\bin\\win64\\uninstall.exe C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b"
"DisplayIcon"="C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin\\win64\\matlab.ico"
"InstallLocation"="C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b"
"DisplayVersion"="9.1"
"URLInfoAbout"="www.mathworks.com"
"Publisher"="MathWorks"
"HelpLink"="www.mathworks.com/support"
"Comments"=" "    

ê[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SoftWare\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Matlab
R2016b]
“DisplayName””MATLAB R201 6b”
“UninstallString””C: \\Prograrn
Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\uninstall\\bin\\win64\\uninstall.exe C: \\Prograrn
Files\\frIATLAB\\R201 6b”
“Displaylcon””C:\\Prograrn Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin\\win64\\matlab. ico”
“InstallLocation””C: \\Prograrn Files\\MATLAB\\R201 6b”
“DisplayVersion””9. 1”
“URLlnfoAbout””www. mathworks. corn”
“Publisher”=”MathWorks”
“HelpLink””www. rnathworks. corn/support”
“Comments”” “
```

Comment: Your script should work just fine (I've just tested it). Maybe your (Windows) editor is confused by a newline (``\n``) missing at the end of the line (try adding after ``... + publisher + "\n")``.

Comment: What should I do then, I can't download anything, canopy is all I have.

Comment: Try adding a newline ``\n``.

Comment: Thank you. you are right, since write does not give its own \n, but the more pressing issue is that the first three if statements do not work.

Comment: How do you know these if statements don't work?

Comment: In my own code I have put print line in the if statements, and nothing is printed

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your environment (canopy?), because the Python code you posted works when run with standard Python (on Linux).

Comment: hmm, maybe but we do not even have standard Python here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your last if statement is completely reversed. It should be or instead of and in order for your statement to work properly.

Comment: I am taking about the first three if statements. Sorry if that was not clear, but you are right. Thank you for the correction. I will change those to or

Answer (score 0):

What about checking in a different way using find()?

```
if line.find("DisplayName") != -1:
    do stuff.
```

I ran this fine, here's the code:

```
fileName = "export.txt"
outputFileName = input("Enter the Output File Name")
inputFile = open(fileName, "r")
outputFile = open(outputFileName, "w")
displayName = ""
displayVersion = ""
publisher = ""

for line in inputFile:
    print line
    if line.find("DisplayName") != -1:
        lst = line.split("=")
        displayName = lst[1][1:len(lst[1])-2]

    if line.find("DisplayVersion") != -1:
        print "here2"
        lst = line.split("=")
        displayVersion = lst[1][1:len(lst[1])-2]
    if line.find("Publisher") != -1:
        print "here3"
        lst = line.split("=")
        publisher = lst[1][1:len(lst[1])-2]
    if displayName!= "" and displayVersion != "" and publisher != "":
        print "Here4"
        print displayName + "\t" + displayVersion + "\t" +publisher
        outputFile.write(displayName + "\t" + displayVersion + "\t" +publisher)
        displayName = ""
        displayVersion = ""
        publisher = ""

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

produces:
    MATLAB R2016b   9.1     MathWorks

The output while running the script looks like this:

Enter the Output File Name"out.txt"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SoftWare\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Matlab R2016b]

"DisplayName"="MATLAB R2016b"

"UninstallString"="C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\uninstall\bin\win64\uninstall.exe C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b"

"DisplayIcon"="C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64\matlab.ico"

"InstallLocation"="C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b"

"DisplayVersion"="9.1"

here2
"URLInfoAbout"="www.mathworks.com"

"Publisher"="MathWorks"

here3
Here4
MATLAB R2016b   9.1 MathWorks
"HelpLink"="www.mathworks.com/support"

"Comments"=" "

Comment: Nope nothing changes. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: hmm, for me none of the here1, here2, here3, here4, are printed. do you want me to send you the whole text file so you can try  it.

Comment: This gives me the following output while I run it. Posted above.

Comment: ok I do not know what to do then, for me nothing is being written to the text file. Maybe my ide is bad or something.

Comment: Is it not reading lines correctly or is it not going into the if statements?  Is the line printed right when the for loop starts?  If not, that suggests something is wrong with the formatting of your input file.  Since I copy/pasted your input file into a new file, maybe my format works.  If its not printing lines, try copying your input file and pasting it into a vi or nano and resaving it.

Comment: It also might be worth it to try running it on this test snippet you provided.

Comment: Ok I ran it on the test snippet and it does not work. Also it is printing the lines, just the prints in the if statements do not print

Comment: Did you change the code to the version I posted above?  Also, could you paste the output you get here?  Might be helpful.

Comment: Yes I changed it to your code. Nothing is written to the output, and I put in the post what was printed

Comment: The printed stuff looks a little weird, but that is because I had to use one note to get the text from a photo. I can't copy it from canopy for some reason.

Comment: Try running python manually from the command line.  Just go to the command line, do python myscript.py, enter "out.txt" when it prompts you, and see what happens then.

If I were you I would just be trying to run my python stuff in a mac/linux environment, at at the very least on the command prompt.  Do you have access to such an environment?

Comment: I used the command prompt, and there is still nothing in the output file

Comment: The first thing we need to figure out is if it's reading the lines properly.  Start with just a for loop:
  
  for line in inputFile:
        print line

If it prints the input file exactly and correctly, each line, then we can move on to the if parts.

Comment: Yes, it successfully prints every line of the input

Comment: Can you copy and paste the output from that into your original question so I can look at it?  Ok the next step, just add a single if statement to your for loop, if line.find("DisplayName") != -1: print "Inside If"

Comment: I can't copy and paste the output for some reason. Inside If is never printed.

Comment: you can copy from the command prompt with right click -> copy, but not always on windows with ctrl+c.

Is the output identical in every way to the input?  Or are there any differences?  Are the \\ backslashes effecting it?  Are the quotes?  Are the line breaks where you expect them to be?

Comment: I am not using command prompt. When I use it, it automatically closes after finishing, so I can't copy. I am still using canopy.

Comment: You need to open command prompt by yourself and navigate to the right directory, then run the code with python myscript.py

Comment: ■" D i s p l a y N a m e " = " M A T L A B   R 2 0 1 6 b "
" U n i n s t a l l S t r i n g " = " C : \ \ P r o g r a m   F i l e s \ \ M A
T L A B \ \ R 2 0 1 6 b \ \ u n i n s t a l l \ \ b i n \ \ w i n 6 4 \ \ u n i
n s t a l l . e x e   C : \ \ P r o g r a m   F i l e s \ \ M A T L A B \ \ R 2
0 1 6 b "
" D i s p l a y I c o n " = " C : \ \ P r o g r a m   F i l e s \ \ M A T L A B
\ \ R 2 0 1 6 b \ \ b i n \ \ w i n 6 4 \ \ m a t l a b . i c o "
" I n s t a l l L o c a t i o n " = " C : \ \ P r o g r a m   F i l e s \ \ M A
T L A B \ \ R 2 0 1 6 b "